# Strategy for sharing and reusing of schema parts in mongoose.js

Tags: database, node.js, mongoose, schema

Suppose, I have two schemas, e.g. for `person` and `company`. Both of them should have an `address`, which consists of a `street name`, `number`, `zip` and `city`.

What would be the strategy to avoid copying the `address` properties between the two schema definitions? I read about [sub docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), but they seem to be (1) tied to exactly one parent schema, (2) always occur in an array.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553941/sub-schemas-on-mongoose-without-arrays

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Almost too obvious, but this is what I came up with finally:

Define the reusable portions separately, however, contrary to my first thoughts: do *not* use a `Schema` here:

```
var addressSubschema = {
    street: String, number: String, zip: String, city: String
}
```

Simply include this part in actual schemas:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String },
    address: addressSubschema
});
var companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    addresses: [addressSubschema]
});
```

Comment: what if some of those parts are required?

Comment: You put a `required: true`, as in the example.

Comment: Idk if that is a good solution, this way, ids will be generated for each address object. Also the Schema constructor has a lot more options. I'm currently just creating an address Schema, like: new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, { _id: false }) and then use that inside my parent schemas. But that is also a bit sketchy i think

Answer (score 0):

My (naive?) approach might be to create a new schema for address, and use Mongoose's [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) mechanic to link to a given address by ObjectID. However, this is essentially emulating a relational DB behaviour, and I'm not sure how PC that is when using a flat-file store like Mongo.

Comment: If you'd like me to explain population a bit more in-depth, just let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but that was what I originally wanted to avoid (because of the reasons you gave :) ).